# How do I read thousand of files into memory without exhausting file descriptors?

Tags: ocaml

I am reading thousands of files into memory using the following function:

```
let read_file f =
  let rec f f_channel s =
      try
        let line = input_line f_channel in
        hash_helper f_channel (s^line^"\n")
      with
      | End_of_file -> s
  in
  f (open_in f) ""
```

However, once the number of files exceed a certain number, my program crashes during runtime with the following exception:

```
Fatal error: executable program file not found
```

Googling the error brings up the following:

https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/1633

It seems to have something to do with file descriptors being exhausted.

Is there a way to read all those files without exhausting the file descriptors? I would have assumed the Pervasives `input_line` function would use some kind of job queue to prevent exhausting and crashing the program.

Edit:

I didn't realise you needed to close the `in_channel`. Here's my new `read_file` implementation:

```
let read_file f =
  let rec hash_helper f_channel s =
      try
        let line = input_line f_channel in
        hash_helper f_channel (s^line^"\n")
      with
      | End_of_file ->
        close_in f_channel;
        s
  in
  hash_helper (open_in f) ""
```

Comment: A file descriptor is an operating system resource, so you have to be careful to release it promptly. You can also read thousands or even millions of files into the memory by using the POSIX mmap facility. You can close the descriptor as soon as the file is mapped, and the memory won't be allocated until it is accessed so that you can read terabytes of files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to close your files.

```
let read_file f =
  let rec f f_channel s =
      try
        let line = input_line f_channel in
        hash_helper f_channel (s^line^"\n")
      with
      | End_of_file -> close_in f_channel; s
  in
  f (open_in f) ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux you can change the number of file descriptors as follows  as the root user:

Edit the following line in the /etc/sysctl.conf file:

```
fs.file-max = value
```

value is the new file descriptor limit that you want to set.

Apply the change by running the following command:

```
/sbin/sysctl -p
```